# Coldfusion counting based on patterns matching

Tags: arrays, coldfusion, pattern-matching, cfml, accumulator

I am reading numbers off a database and create a 4 digits patterns such as:

```
1, 2, 2, 1
0, 2, 2, 2
4, 0, 2, 0
1, 2, 2, 1
2, 1, 1, 2
```

Each digit can only be from 0-6. The second step is where my problem is.  I need to tally each pattern.  For example, pattern 1,2,2,1 has a tally of 2 because it appears twice and the other patterns appear only once each.

At the end output, I need to be able to display each unique pattern with the count such as:

```
1, 2, 2, 1 - 2
0, 2, 2, 2 - 1
4, 0, 2, 0 - 1
2, 1, 1, 2 - 1
```

I was thinking of using a 2-dimensional array. Where

```
combinations[1][1]="1, 2, 2, 1" (the pattern)
combinations[1][2]=2 (the count)
combinations[2][1]="0, 2, 2, 2"
combinations[2][2]=1
etc.
```

How can I actually create the array dynamically while matching the pattern? i.e. if the pattern is not yet found add to the array.  If it is found, add to the count.  I have tried this:

```
<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#ArrayLen(combinations)#">
    <cfif not arrayFind(combinations[i][1],"#patterns#")>
        <cfset arrayAppend(combinations,["#patterns#",1]) >
    <cfelse>
        <cfset combinations[i][2] = combinations[i][2] + 1>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

But I am getting the error on the ArrayFind:

```
Object of type class java.lang.String cannot be used as an array
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: The answer might be in your opening paragraph where you refer to a database and pattern creation.  Please elaborate on that part.

Comment: Why not just SELECT the fields and do a COUNT(*)?

Comment: The database doesn't contain the pattern.  The patterns are created after processing the data, so cannot do COUNT.

Comment: So you're querying the database for numbers, then using those numbers to count unique patterns? This can likely still be done at the database level and save yourself some processing. What database and approx how many rows and unique patterns are you working with?

Comment: The numbers in the database are actually 1-49.  I need to put them into slots based on some criteria. A pattern is created after the process.  Don't think this can be done within the DB.  The DB only has 4K records.

Comment: Depends on the criteria. It is possible a CASE statement may work, but hard to say without more details.

Answer (score 1):

Solved my own question.  Looks like I used the wrong function. This works:

```
<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#ArrayLen(combinations)#">
    <cfif Find(combinations[i][1],"#patterns#")>
        <cfset combinations[i][2] = combinations[i][2] + 1>
        <cfset found = 1>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
<cfif not found>
    <cfset arrayAppend(combinations,["#patterns#",1]) >
</cfif>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a 2-dimensional array, you could also use a structure instead, in which the keys are the patterns and the values the counts. That naturally avoids duplicates because the keys of a structure can only exist once.

The code for creating the structure would look something like this:

```cfml
<cfset combinations = {}>
<cfloop query="#dbresults#">
  <cfif not structKeyExists(combinations, dbresults.pattern)>
    <cfset combinations[dbresults.pattern] = 1>
  <cfelse>
    <cfset combinations[dbresults.pattern]++>
  </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

In the end you just have to loop over the structure to output the counts:

```cfml
<cfloop collection="#combinations#" item="pattern">
  <cfoutput><p>#pattern# - #combinations[pattern]#</p></cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```